Unable to Display Two XML Layouts in One Activity Using Fragments
I am facing an issue with my Android project where I am trying to display two XML layouts in one activity and switch between them using fragments. Here's a breakdown of my setup:
1.Activity Structure: I have a single activity (ActivityMenuIcon) in my project.
2.Layouts:
The first XML layout (activity_menu_menu.xml) contains a button. Upon clicking this button, I want to display a mini form from another XML layout.
The second XML layout (fragment1.xml) is supposed to be displayed upon clicking the button.
3.Fragment Implementation: I've attempted to achieve this functionality by implementing fragments in my activity. Here's a simplified version of my Java code:
    package com.example.myapplication;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
    import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
    import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

    public class ActivityMenuIcon extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button addbutton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_menu);

        addbutton = findViewById(R.id.addBtt);
        addbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                replaceFragment(new fragment1());
            }
        });
    }

    private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.layout1, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
    }

4.XML Layouts:
activity_menu_menu.xml:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    tools:context=".fragment1">
    
    <!-- Comment: XML code here -->
    </FrameLayout>

fragment1.xml:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragment2">

     <!-- Comment: XML code here -->

</FrameLayout>

Despite my efforts, I'm unable to successfully display the second XML layout (fragment1.xml) upon clicking the button in the first layout (activity_menu_menu.xml). The expected behavior is that upon clicking the button, the fragment containing fragment1.xml should replace the current layout.
I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to properly implement this functionality using fragments. If there are any errors or improvements needed in my approach, please let me know. Thank you for your assistance!

"the fragment containing fragment1.xml should replace the current layout" - unless your 'current layout' is a fragment itself (i.e., you are replacing one fragment by another one), the 'current layout' won't be affected.

ok thanks for information ,but if i wanted to have a single activity with an initial XML layout set, and upon pressing a button, another XML layout should appear on top of the initial one (I want to create a mini-form that appears at the bottom of the screen) .How can I achieve this?
